# I think someone is trying to scare me with their SSID name

Tags: windows, windows-10, wireless-networking, ssid

This is occurring on my Windows 10 Laptop.

So I was just minding my own business when I accidentally pressed the Airplane mode button.  Naturally I reconnect to the WiFi but whilst doing so I spotted an SSID name a few places down. **The name of the connection was the exact same as one of my personal usernames from a game I use to play about a year or 2 ago, as well as my current age and it's freaking me out**. I've considered it may be a coincidence but it's obviously much more targeted, at least I'm seeing it that way.
 It wouldn't be anyone from my family trying to pull a prank on me with their hotspots or anything of the sorts as I'm currently home alone, and they couldn't possibly know the username I used to play the game. Additionally, my neighbors couldn't possibly know such a personal thing either.

My name on the game was 'Olives' and I was about 15-16 when I played it, and I never gave it my age. (I'm now 17 and still to this day I never enter my age online besides for in this post now. I typically set my date-of-birth to something like 1999 as well out of habit, and also because most things require you to be 18 or older. This applies for my Microsoft account I use on my PC.)
 Attached below is a screenshot I managed to take of it as it appeared;

[image: Olives17 connection that appeared]

Apologies if this isn't helpful, but this is what I saw and what startled me.

I'm currently connected to another connection point in my house so I'm running on a different IP address if that makes any difference. I also ran the following on cmd.exe to hopefully prevent it from popping up again:

```
netsh wlan add filter permission=block ssid="(name)" networktype=infrastructure
```

I'm not tech savvy at all. I'm running off what a website instructed me after searching 'how to block a wifi connection'.

This is my first time posting here and I'm very rattled. Does anyone know what might be going on? Should I be scared or am I overthinking it?

Thank you all for your help.

**UPDATE!:** It seems to have been resolved after running the command (as mentioned above) on cmd.exe as it is no longer appearing, and it hasn't given me any issues. Still curious what may have happened here, but everything seems fine.

Comment: Is this a mobile device? A phone? A laptop? Until more info my vote is for `my family trying to pull a prank on me`. If it was malicious you would not name it something that got your attention. Add a screenshot of the SSID to your question? How to add a good inline image that improves the question:  Copy and paste in the body. Windows has an inbuilt hotkey (Win + Shift + S) which executes Snipping Tool. Any screen captured will be copied to the clipboard.

Comment: Thank you for your help! This is my first time using this website and posting something, so thank you for the tips

Comment: After seeing your screenshot, it's highly likely it's a coincidence

Comment: I just added some updated info to the post if it makes any difference. Thank you for replying, all help is appreciated

Comment: Someone must be playing a prank on you. He is changing his mobile hotspot name and that appears to be here. Btw Any of ur friend live nearby?

Comment: You didn't say whether it is a mobile device. Is your question about your Windows 10 laptop or Windows 10 desktop?

Comment: Windows 10 Laptop.

To answer the previous question, no, none live close. Based on the information I've been given i'm no longer as worried as I was yesterday; just a coincidence. Unless someone believes there is a problem I am open to any possibility.

Answer (score 1):

It is just coincidence. Turning on Airplane Mode and then turning it back OFF just resets DNS.  It does not affect your Wireless and that will just reconnect as it did. The SSIDs are what it sees and recent connections that you had connected to.

Nothing to worry about.

If you wish, you can remove unused wireless profiles to reduce the SSIDs you see. Remove all, then add the one wireless profile you need right now. Follow these steps.

1. Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
2. Type in   netsh wlan show profiles  and press enter to see the list.
3. netsh wlan delete profile name="profile name"
4. Ensure the profile was deleted.
5. Do this for all profiles, OR, all but the one you are using.
6. Close out, restart your computer and test it.

Comment: My only concern with that is that I've never paired my age and the username together before, nor have I used the same username on any other website or service besides for the game (which i haven't played in quite a while now). I definitely trust your word in tech-savviness I just feel a little confused. Thank you

Comment: SSIDs are separate from your other information, so for connections you had made before, it is just seeing that data. Nothing (I can see here) to be worried about.

Comment: See above to remove superfluous wireless profiles.